# How I get the calculation in same page when I select drop down value?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How can I get the result of calculation in same page when I select drop down value?

I have tried with ajax. But not fixed. I am new to jquery and ajax.

```
<!-- drop down selection -->
<select>                                                                 
<option value='1'>1 Pax</option>                                                                 
<option value='2'>2 Pax</option>
<option value='3'>3 Pax</option>
</select>

<p>Price per each: $100</p>

<!-- calculating here -->
<p>Total price: $100 x Value of pax)</p>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: You don't need ajax to make calculation. You can use either jQuery or vanilla javascript.

Comment: Depends on where you calculation is and what it does.  The question implies you already have a server-side calculation that may use non-client-side data to make that calculation which you are currently using a POST for.   So you would need ajax in that case.  However, it looks like you just want "price * 100", so no need for ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use jquery. You don't need to use ajax for the calculation.

You need to get the value of the `select` tag and put it on a variable
then you can parse it to integer so you can use it to calculate the total price.
Check the example below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pax" onchange="calculate()">
  <option value='1' selected>1 Pax</option>
  <option value='2'>2 Pax</option>
  <option value='3'>3 Pax</option>
</select>
<p>Price per each: $100</p>
<p>Total: <span id="total"></span></p>
<script>
  function calculate() {
    var get_value = $("#pax option:selected").text();
    var no_pax = parseInt(get_value);
    var price = 100;
    var total_price = no_pax * price;

    $("#total").text(total_price);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using jquery, then you probably don't want to use `onchange` - better to set up an event with jquery `$("#pax").change(function() { $(this).val(); })`

Answer (score 1):

You can use vanilla JS [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to update the calculation and not AJAX.

```js
// Store HTML elements in JS variables
const paxSelectEle = document.getElementById("pax-select");
const totalPriceEle = document.getElementById("total-price");

// Listen for a change in #pax-select 
paxSelectEle.addEventListener("change", () => {
  // Set the HTML of the total price to
  // 100 * #pax-select value
  totalPriceEle.innerHTML = 100 * paxSelectEle.value;
});
```

```html
<!-- drop down selection -->
<select id="pax-select">
  <option value='1'>1 Pax</option>   
  <option value='2'>2 Pax</option>
  <option value='3'>3 Pax</option>
</select>

<p>Price per each: $100</p>

<!-- calculating here -->
<p>Total price: $<span id="total-price">100</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code

```js
$("#ddldemo").change(function() {
  $("#ldldemo").text(100 * parseInt($("#ddldemo").val()));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <select id="ddldemo" name="ddldemo">
    <option value='1'>1 Pax</option>
    <option value='2'>2 Pax</option>
    <option value='3'>3 Pax</option>
  </select>
  <label id="ldldemo"></label>
  <p>Total price: $100 x Value of pax)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do it:

1) Giving an `id`(`valueselection`) to `select` option for differentiating with another `select` element.

2) Put base price and total price inside `label` with unique `id` similar to step 1)

3) Calculate initial and price on selected option:

```
var i= 1;
var base=$('label#baseprice').text();
$('label#total').text(base);
$("select#valueselection").change(function(){
  i=$('select#valueselection').val();
  $('label#total').text(base*i);
});
```

See snippet below:

```js
var i= 1;
var base=$('label#baseprice').text();
$('label#total').text(base);
$("select#valueselection").change(function(){
  i=$('select#valueselection').val();
  $('label#total').text(base*i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- drop down selection -->
<select id="valueselection">                                                                 
<option value='1'>1 Pax</option>                                                                 
<option value='2'>2 Pax</option>
<option value='3'>3 Pax</option>
</select>

<p>Price per each: $<label id="baseprice">100</label></p>

<!-- calculating here -->
<p>Total price: $<label id="total"></label></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#pax").change(function(e) {
  var price = 100;
  $("#total").html($(this).val() * price)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pax">
  <option value='0'>Select Pax</option>
  <option value='1'>1 Pax</option>
  <option value='2'>2 Pax</option>
  <option value='3'>3 Pax</option>
</select>
<p>Price per each: $100</p>
<p>Total: <span id="total"></span></p>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.